# Connect to UofU WPA2Enterprise

Tags: wireless, network-manager

I'm trying to connect to a WPA2Enterprise connection so I can stay connected at the University I study at. I initially tried to connect via the gui, but I couldn't specify some of the things that the connection requires, and after a while of googling I haven't had much luck getting it any closer.

The requirements are [here](http://setup.utah.edu/Clinical-UConnect/generic_os.html), but I'll post them for posterity.

```
Wireless Network Name (SSID) :      UConnect
Security Type :  WPA2-Enterprise
Encryption Type :  AES (CCMP)
EAP Method :  PEAP
Phase 2 (Inner Method) :  EAP-MSCHAPV2
Root CA Certificate(s) : [links below] Install Entrust.net Secure Server Certification Authority Install AddTrust External CA Root
User Certificate :  <N/A>
Anonymous Identity (Outer Identity) :  <Leave Blank>
Username (Identity) :  uNID@clinical
Password :  [Your Password]
```

- [Install Entrust.net Secure Server Certification Authority](http://setup.utah.edu/Clinical-UConnect/rootca_1172_5268_0.cer)
- [Install AddTrust External CA Root](http://setup.utah.edu/Clinical-UConnect/rootca_1172_5268_1.cer)

So far I've been trying to tinker and research what I need, but I'm not having much luck. To install the root certs I ran.

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/uconnect
sudo wget -P /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/uconnect http://setup.utah.edu/Clinical-UConnect/rootca_1172_5268_0.cer http://setup.utah.edu/Clinical-UConnect/rootca_1172_5268_1.cer
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

For the actual profile I've got in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` so far I have:

```
[connection]
id=UConnect
uuid=c7f10f15-d0e1-47a9-bf44-e8c71e6131d0
type=802-11-wireless

[802-11-wireless]
ssid=UConnect
mode=infrastructure
security=802-11-wireless-security

[802-11-wireless-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-eap

[ipv4]
method=auto

[ipv6]
method=auto

[802-1x]
eap=peap;
identity=[my-school-id]@clinical
phase2-auth=mschapv2
password-flags=1
system-ca-certs=true
```

Any help would be super appreciated, so (as always) thanks in advance!

Comment: Any suggestions that people give me might not be attempted today, they're closing the library earlier than normal (I forgot this is the summer semester)

Comment: You didn't need to edit `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` manually. In KDE, I can set the options for all of the fields (except for Encryption Type, which doesn't need to be set, and the certificate, which *might* work if left blank), and GNOME should have the fields as well.

Comment: at my university, I have to select PEAP and then MSCHAPV2, and finally ignore the lack of certificate. I had a hard time to find it, but now I can connect everywhere in my country. I never got the connexion on LXDE, but with Unity or Gnome it works like a charm. Maybe it'll be the same messy thing in Utah ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after trying a few various combinations I found one that worked. I'll include a screenshot of my config as well as a copy of the profile for reference.
[image]

```
[ipv6]
method=auto

[connection]
id=UConnect
uuid=0a6b22c4-e9ae-430b-98b1-5601d69ae714
type=802-11-wireless

[802-11-wireless]
ssid=UConnect
mode=infrastructure
mac-address=6C:71:D9:72:DA:0D
security=802-11-wireless-security

[802-1x]
eap=peap;
identity=[redacted]@utah.edu
ca-cert=/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/uconnect/rootca_1172_5268_1.cer
phase2-auth=mschapv2
password-flags=1
system-ca-certs=true

[ipv4]
method=auto

[802-11-wireless-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-eap
auth-alg=open
```